# How to know if some data already exists on a device disk?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, block-device, mkfs

The simple way to check if disk include  filesystem is to do:

```
mount /grid/sdb /mnt
```

and if sdb or other /dev/sdx have file-system then mount will be succeeded, if not. Probably file system exists!

But this is an ugly way to check that.

What the other elegant alternative to check file-system on disk?

My target is to check if file-system already configured on disk's as /dev/sdb - /dev/sdx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot to check filesystem on disks is the `lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,MODE`

It is a list block devices command which will output all your block, hard devices on your machine. With theese option you will get something you want to achieve:

```
$ sudo lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,MODE
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL     UUID                                 MODE
sda                                                               brw-rw----
├─sda1      ntfs   WinHyperX 2D6BFC4E0CDCFAD8                     brw-rw----
├─sda2      ext4   HyperX    ef761208-bab3-4a26-87d2-ed21a7f5a1bb brw-rw----
└─sda3      swap             74259007-a80b-4866-b059-0bdbe6331040 brw-rw----
sdb                                                               brw-rw----
└─sdb1      ext4   4TB       91e32977-0656-45b8-bcf5-14acce39d9c2 brw-rw----
sr0                                                               brw-rw----
mmcblk0                                                           brw-rw----
└─mmcblk0p1 exfat            9C33-6BBC                            brw-rw----
```

Just to add, if you just simply want to see if there is or not a filesystem on a disk and you dont want to know which or what is it you could also use this command `file -s /dev/sda1` or even list `fdisk -l` which I think shows all disks and returns error when disk has no filesystem on it.